# Как создать читалку на android?

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать читалку, но не имею ни малейшего понятия куда двигаться. Как я понимаю, нужно получить файл, допустим, fb2, открыть его и отобразить на экране пользователя в форматированном виде. Как можно отформатировать этот самый файл? Точнее, какой метод этим занимается? Быть может, есть какие-нибудь туториалы? Я искала, но ничего не нашла(((

Comment: Начните с ознакомления с форматом [fb2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FictionBook). Это стандартный xml, так что берите xml-парсер и...

Comment: можете посмотреть исходники опенсорсного ридера, как [FBReader](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ). Здесь же решают конкретные проблемы с кодом, а не указывают направления движения и прочее обобщенное